# Don't stretch Camera preview inside SurfaceView in portrait mode

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview

What my code do is take image from camera and show it inside surfaceview in fullscreen, but preview is stretched upward (so an object like a bottle appear higher and thinner than reality). This is my code:

```
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
    Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
    Camera.Size result = getBestPreviewSize(params, width, height);

    params.setPreviewSize(result.width, result.height);

    params.setPictureFormat(ImageFormat.JPEG);
    params.setJpegQuality(100);
    params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
    params.setPictureSize(dpWidth, dpWidth);
    params.setRotation(90);
    mCamera.setParameters(params);

    mCamera.startPreview();

}

public Camera.Size getBestPreviewSize(Camera.Parameters params, int width,
        int height) {

    Camera.Size result = null;
    for (Camera.Size size : params.getSupportedPreviewSizes()) {
        Log.d("size: ", size.width + ":" + size.height);
        if (size.width <= width && size.height <= height) {
            if (result == null) {
                result = size;
            } else {
                int resultArea = result.width * result.height;
                int newArea = size.width * size.height;

                if (newArea > resultArea) {
                    result = size;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

what's wrong?

Comment: Do you mean like this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/15128388/2060383 ?

Comment: yes, something like that, but i don't use landscape mode, only portrait

Comment: Do you just want to reduce the size of the SurfaceView to maintain the aspect ratio of the camera input?

Comment: I would show camera preview in fullscreen (has happen inside default android camera) without distort image

Comment: @giozh   have u found solution of your question i m also facing same issue